Expiation for Chandalas and other mixed Varnas
Are their any dharmashastras or other vedic works which discuss how a Chandala through pious activities can reform himself into a respectable member of society and abandon the vile and disgusting jobs ordained to them?
I don't Know Samskritam, but these works may guide you.
Śūdrāhnika
trīśūdratīrthavidhi
Śuddhiviveka
Clarification: I mean through Vedas or Dharmashastras should've made that clear sorry.

Certain jobs in society are disgusting like that .. if no one does them do you suggest the use of robots?

In Tantra Lord Shiva says a Chandala who knows the Hamsa mantra is more pious than a Brahmin who is unaware.

@Rickross well today's world yes, but Chandalas were outcasted and seen as impure due to these acts, which is wrong if they had access to hygiene and various other facilities. So, did a Chandala have the ability to do rituals to purify themselves?

@Rickross Either they were forced to do these disgusting jobs, or they had the ability to take pious action and purify themselves and hence integrate into society.

The vidhāna which sat-śūdras follow, cāṇḍāla can follow too, they may do pañcamahāyajñas, do śravaṇa of itihāsa-purāṇa and dharmaśāstras from Brāhmaṇas, do sevā of Brāhmaṇas, do japa of Bhagavān nāma and nāmasaṅkīrtana, avoiding madyapāna and māṁsabhakṣaṇa, follow sāmānya dharmas, do dānakarma, tīrthāṭana, etc. There are no disgusting jobs, jobs are jobs after all. Even executors of criminals in royal courts, one of the roles played by cāṇḍālas, is an important job.

But a cāṇḍāla may avoid some niṣiddha karman, such as selling salt, indulging in gamanam outside of vivāha and other such kind of works, same as the case with sat-śūdras. That dvijas shouldn't do sparśa of cāṇḍālas would still hold though.

@Bingming yet if a Chandala is verified to be pious should one not hesitate to touch him of course one shouldn't be attached to such. Also, another question is a Chandala allowed to find work outside of the work prescribed on this basis.

Work of a Shudra I mean certainly not that of Dvijas.

I think some works of Śūdras can be open to Cāṇḍālas, such as work in skilled professions, like pottery, weaving, crafting, etc.

@Bingming probs, but I need scriptural refrences, because while commentaries say a Chandala can leave the sinful profession of their tradition from what I have read I see no proof in that I did refer to Sanskrit Manuscripts of low caste ceremonies and practices.
